# recoding malloc: code signing blocked mmap()

Tags: c, memory, malloc, shared-libraries

I am actually recoding malloc, using an avl, and when i test it with a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="libft_malloc.so"
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1`
$@
```

and then ./script ls or ./script vim, it works well. But when i export manually the variables in my shell, i have this error:

```
dyld: warning: could not load inserted library 'libft_malloc.so' into 
library validated process because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    libft_malloc.so: code signing blocked mmap() of 'libft_malloc.so'
```

here is how is use mmap:

```
pges_ctrl.header_pge = mmap(NULL, getpagesize() * NB_PAGES, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
if (pges_ctrl.header_pge == MAP_FAILED)
    return (0);
```

and

```
tmp = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
if (tmp == MAP_FAILED)
{
    pges_ctrl.errors |= MMAP_BAD_ALLOC;
    return NULL;
}
```

If you have idea about what could be the cause of it, or how i could debug that, that would help a lot !
I am working on Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6

Compiled with gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror
Thanks for the help!